# Strange armatures on model after import

Tags: armature

I imported a Milkshape 3D (MS3D) model into Blender and the armature looks like this, with very tiny dots for the joints. It is functional, but what is this, and how can I convert it to a more traditional-looking Blender armature?

https://pasteall.org/media/2/5/25a85853ab9cc1b258203a8f5fbd23e5.blend

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Added, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bones are displayed as *Sticks*, you can change that for *Octahedrals* for example:

[image]

Also, they are very small, you can select them all in *Edit* mode, activate the *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins* option, and scale them up:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This has been driving me crazy with multiple files!

Answer (score 6):

This happens when the file is created with a software that considers joints/bones as single point entities.
Blender is one of the few software that gives joints both a start and an end points, most of other softwares just don't have a distinct end point, joints just either "end" and the next child, or have no lengths. And, to be clear, Blender's bones end points has no functional purpose, it's just a display preference.

So when you import such file with no endpoints, Blender has to basically invent new endpoints. And one of the ways he does it is by just "extruding" it from the start point by a static lenght on a single axis.

I think some importers have options like "import leaf bones" that will try to reproduce that.

Other than that, you can try to manually grab the endpoints and move them to their child bones' heads, but be aware that it effectively changes your bones orientations, affecting how the associated meshes will be deformed.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on explaining why!